# GMap Location Center - According to pin

Tags: 7, location, google-maps

The Gmap location field marker is located by default at the center of the map. 
How can change that ? 
I want the center of the map to be calculated according to the value that i have entered. 
For example : Lat: 33.5 Long: -70.2

I want the center's coordinates to be Lat-x , Long - y .